# Simple JOTM Questions

Tags: java, jta

I'm starting to use JOTM and have a few simple questions:

- If I start an embedded JOTM instance, can I perform a 2 phase commit between a remote database (with an XA enabled driver) and a local JMS queue initiated by a 3rd party client?
- Does my JOTM instance require both the Database and JMS provider .jar files on the classpath if a remote client is performing the transaction or only if the transaction is initiated via a local client?

Regards,

Chris